# Maven archetype for java ee 6 and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa, archetypes

I need to create a java ee 6 project which contains:

- JSF
- EJB
- JPA

The Web-things should be compiled to a .war file, the ejb to the ejb-jar and overall into an ear file. The application will be deployed to a Glassfish v3.

I was looking for a maven archetype which I can use and integrate into Eclipse. However I haven't found one. Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a JSF2.2 + EJB3 + JPA2 project using maven archetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494487/how-to-create-a-jsf2-2-ejb3-jpa2-project-using-maven-archetype)

Answer (score 0):

I consider [Andy Gibson's Knappsack Archetype](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/projects/knappsack/) as a good starting point for what you are looking for. It gives you certain levels of working projects from a very basic setup to one filled with examples.

Alternatively, [Adam Bien's Weblog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/kicktarting_real_world_java_ee) is always a good place for finding simple solutions as for example a minimal project setup.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java EE MVC Security Archetype](https://github.com/karlnicholas/javaee-security-quickstart-archetype) is a quickstart for websites that want user self registration and security configuration.

You can [try it out on Openshift](http://mvc-jsec.rhcloud.com/), though sometimes you have to wait a couple of minutes for openshift to load and start the application.

The archetype includes the following technologies:

- Java EE MVC web application for Wildly 9 environment
- JSF 2.2 and Bootstrap
- JPA 2.1
- H2DB (H2 Development Database)
- JUnit/Arquillian/Drone/Graphene for testing
- Java EE SecuritySupported by JBoss/Wildfly Database Module

Please note: This post is self-promotional.

Comment: Please do review [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) before creating any more posts about this project.